# Emacs lisp: Get directory name (not path) from the path

Tags: emacs, path, directory, cross-platform, elisp

I am looking for a *simple* and *portable* way of obtaining the last component of the directory path or the directory itself from the path. The semantics of the function should be something like this:

```
(get-dirname-nonpath "/some/dir/")  ;; should return "dir"
(get-dirname-nonpath "C:\Windows\Path") ;; should return "Path"
(get-dirname-nonpath "/some/path/to/my/source.ext")  ;; returns "my"
```

In the last example it is also fine if the function returns "source.ext" instead of "my", especially if that would make it shorter.
Looking at the emacs, I am unable to find a built-in function that would help in achieving this:

Of course, I could do some string manipulation with (back)slashes, but that looks messy and more like a hack. What is the right way to do it in a robust (OS-oblivious) manner?

**EDIT**: The best I could find so far is: `(file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name ...))`

Answer (score 15):

```lisp
(file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name (file-name-directory ...)))
```

You need the last part, if you want your third example to work:

```lisp
(file-name-nondirectory
   (directory-file-name
     (file-name-directory "/some/path/to/my/source.ext")))
```

returns `"my"`.